# How to check whether it is a blob url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I am converting blobURL to base64 dataURLs, but I want to do this only if url is a blobURL.

So is there any way to check whether it is valid blob url?

my blob url - `blob:http://192.168.0.136/85017e84-0f2d-4791-b563-240794abdcbf`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You are facing an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

You absolutely don't need to check if your blobURI is a valid one, because you absolutely don't need to use the blobURI in order to create a base64 version of the Blob it's pointing to.

The only way to do it is to fetch the Blob and this means creating a copy of its data in memory for no-good.

#### What you need is a way to retrieve this Blob.

There is unfortunately no official way to do so with the web APIs, but it's not that hard to make it ourselves:

We simply have to overwrite the default `URL.createObjectURL` method in order to map the passed Blob in a dictionnary using the blobURI as key:

```js
(() => {
  // overrides URL methods to be able to retrieve the original blobs later on
  const old_create = URL.createObjectURL;
  const old_revoke = URL.revokeObjectURL;
  Object.defineProperty(URL, 'createObjectURL', {
    get: () => storeAndCreate
  });
  Object.defineProperty(URL, 'revokeObjectURL', {
    get: () => forgetAndRevoke
  });
  Object.defineProperty(URL, 'getBlobFromObjectURL', {
    get: () => getBlob
  });
  const dict = {};

  function storeAndCreate(blob) {
    var url = old_create(blob); // let it throw if it has to
    dict[url] = blob;
    return url
  }

  function forgetAndRevoke(url) {
    old_revoke(url);
    // some checks just because it's what the question titel asks for, and well to avoid deleting bad things
    try {
      if(new URL(url).protocol === 'blob:')
        delete dict[url];
    }catch(e){} // avoided deleting some bad thing ;)
  }

  function getBlob(url) {
    return dict[url];
  }
})();

// a few example uses

const blob = new Blob(['foo bar']);
// first normal use everyhting is alive
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const retrieved = URL.getBlobFromObjectURL(url);
console.log('retrieved: ', retrieved);
console.log('is same object: ', retrieved === blob);

// a revoked URL, of no use anymore
const revoked = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
URL.revokeObjectURL(revoked);
console.log('revoked: ', URL.getBlobFromObjectURL(revoked));

// an https:// URL
console.log('https: ', URL.getBlobFromObjectURL(location.href));
```

<sub>PS: for the ones concerned about the case a Blob might be closed (e.g user provided file has been deleted from disk) then simply listen for the `onerror` event of the FileReader you'd use in next step.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

you could do something like

```
 var url = 'blob:http://192.168.0.136/85017e84-0f2d-4791-b563-240794abdcbf';

 if(url.search('blob:') == -1){
   //do something
 }
```

you may also use reg-expression based check with `url.match('url expression')`