# How can I convert the blob url into blob object via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, blob

I try to use the blob url to display the image file on the front view and sent the data to other module via javascript like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          var imagefile_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
          originFiles.push(imagefile_url);
          imageFiles[i] = new Promise(resolve =>{
            _this.autoCropImage(imagefile_url, function(imgData, blob){
              resolve({blobOBJ: blob, cropped:imgData}); //blob is blob object file and imgData is blob url
            });
          })
        }
        Promise.all(imageFiles).then(value=>{
          _this.props.readInputFile(value, originFiles);
        });
```

and I display the image file by `<img scr={this.state.cropped}>`.
But when I want to upload the image file to imgur, I need to convert the `blob url` back to `blob object`.
I use the way to get the blob object is using the state temporary to save the blob object.

As following my code is `formdata.append("image", this.state.blobOBJ)`, but I want to use only one `key(this.state.cropped)`.

Is there the way to convert blob url into blob object?

Comment: use the blob you already got. don't convert it back to a blob

Comment: Might interest you even if not really the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145422/how-to-check-whether-it-is-a-blob-url-using-javascript/49146232#49146232