# Uploading a blob URL to Imgur?

Tags: javascript, image, imgur

Im trying to upload blob url to imgur api:

https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139

it says clearly in docs that it can be: `binary file` or `base64` or `url`

My URL (example): `blob:http://localhost:8080/7e44709-093d-4a4-b167-a3fdfc63a8e`

```
formData.append('image', 'blob:http://localhost:8080/7e44709-093d-4a4-b167-a3fdfc63a8e');
formData.append('type', 'URL');
```

However Im getting `400` error from imgur api that:

```
{"data":{"error":
"Invalid URL (blob:http:\/\/localhost:8080\/7e44729-093d-4aa4-167-a3fdef3a8e)",
"request":"\/3\/image","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":400}
```

Looking forward for help why does it fail and how to upload it properly. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

The image needs to be converted to base64 and then from base64 in to binary. This is done using `.toDataURL()` and `dataURItoBlob()`

## Img => Base64 => Binary

```js
function imgToURI() {
  // Convert image to Base64
  var img = snap.toDataURL();
  // Convert Base64 image to binary
  var file = dataURItoBlob(img);
}

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
// convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
var byteString;
if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
else
    byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
// separate out the mime component
var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
// write the bytes of the string to a typed array
var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```

You could stop at base64 if that's all you need, in my case I needed to convert again to binary so that I could pass the data over to twitter (using OAuth) without use of a db. It turns out you can tweet binary which is pretty cool, twitter will convert it back in to an image.

[I created a blog post about this a few years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425180542/http://blog.devteaminc.co/posting-a-canvas-image-to-twitter-using-oauth/)

Comment: Oh I was hoping that all I need is that localhost URL :( seems like i have to upload base64. thank u for answer :)

Comment: hmm I'm not familiar with imgurs api but yeah you should be good with base64

Comment: You absolutely don't need to go to base64, the blobURI already points to binary data (either in memory or in disk), All you need is to keep the Blob instance that was used to generate this blob URI. And while your blog article is a bit old, note that even there you don't need to go the dataURI way, you can directly use the [HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method.

Answer (score -1):

Since the API accepts binary, you can send the Blob you used to generate this blobURI (the one you must have passed to [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) since it is the only method able to genereate such an URI).

```
formData.append('image', the_original_blob);
formData.append('type', 'file');
```

If you are not responsible of the code that did produce this blobURI <s>you've got a problem.</s>

- you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146232/3702797) which provides a monkey-patch to `URL` methods so that we can retrieve the Blob they point to,
- or you could fetch that blobURI as a Blob again (more memory usage, but still a bit less than going through base64).